# Where can I get a medium-sized project case completed with Mathematica?

Tags: example

I have been using Mathematica for a while, and I have mastered basic grammar. At present, I want to solve some small and medium-sized engineering problems with Mathematica, and I want to know where to find these cases (For example, cases in mechanics or engineering mechanics or numerical analysis).

Comment: You could look at the xyz Models in the [PDEModels Overview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html)

Comment: @user21 Thank you very much for the help document.